# Finding and Removing Duplicate Values in MS Access

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access

I have three columns in Access:

```
ZeroCurveID  MarkRunID  MarkAsOfDate
90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8896*      8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
```

The dataset is several thousand records long.

Each `ZeroCurveID` should have a corresponding `MarkRunID` and a `MarkAsofDate`.
There should only be one corresponding MarkRunID and MarkAsofDate for the same ZeroCurveID.
However, throughout the set, there are a few instances where there will be two different MarkRunIDs for the same MarkasOfDate and ZeroCurveID, like `8896` and `8898` in the example above (shown where starred). I need to identify where these duplicates occur.

How can I identify these instances in the code? What query could I write to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Write a group by query that groups by the fields you have duplicated, and add a COUNT() column that counts by primary key, whatever that is. Then sort the results by the COUNT() column in descending order to see where the count is > 1. Those are your dups.

Comment: ok, I have it GROUP BY dbo_ZeroCurves.ZeroCurveID, dbo_MarkRuns.MarkRunID, dbo_MarkRuns.MarkAsOfDate. 

how do I add a column to count by primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Run the Find Duplicates Wizard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzB-EUvNwCE

Get your Select Query working and then change it to a Delete Query, and run that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amRbEhQWH78